# Calculating the mode value of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror, mode

The function for returning the mode value of an array works on every test except one. When I pass the following array through the function, I get a TypeError. I figured out that it has something to do with the number 0 in the passed array, but I don't know why and I don't know how to solve the problem. This is what my mode function and my typeerror function looks like.

```
 function mode (arr) {
  throwErrors(arr)

  const numberOccurence = {}
  const mostOccurent = []

  for (const numberValues of arr) {
    if (numberOccurence[numberValues]) {
      numberOccurence[numberValues] += 1
    } else {
      numberOccurence[numberValues] = 1
    } 
  }

  let timesOccured = Object.values(numberOccurence)
  let numbersSorted = timesOccured.sort((a, b) => b - a)

  for (const keys of Object.keys(numberOccurence)) {
    if (numberOccurence[keys] === numbersSorted[0]) {
      mostOccurent.push(Number(keys)) 
    }
  }

  return mostOccurent.sort((a, b) => a - b)
}


function throwErrors (functionParameter) {
  if (!Array.isArray(functionParameter)) { 
    throw new TypeError('The passed argument is not an array.')
  } else if (functionParameter.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('The passed array contains no elements.')
  } else if (!functionParameter.every(function checkIfNumber (elements) {
       if ((typeof elements == 'number')){
         return elements
       }
     })) { 
    throw new TypeError('The passed array may only contain valid numbers.')
  } 
}
```

If I pass [3, 5, 2, -5, 9, 2, -5, 5, 10, 4, 1, 0, -1, 9, 0] to the function, I get TypeError: "The passed array may only contain valid numbers", but I expected to get [-5, 0, 2, 5, 9]

Comment: that is the function of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function that you pass to [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) should return a boolean value. If it (the callback function)  returns `true` for every element of array then only the`every` method will return `true`.

Note this line in your callback :

```
if ((typeof elements == 'number')){
         return elements
```

You are returning element instead of boolean value. When the callback returns a `0` it is automatically casted to boolean `false`. and thus the `every()` returns `false` causing function to throw the `TypeError`.

Fix the callback :

```
//renaming `elements` to `element` as it's single element
//return the result of boolean expression instead of using if statement explicitly
function checkIfNumber (element) { 
       return typeof element == 'number';
}
```

Can be written as ES6 arrow function :

```
const checkIfNumber = element => typeof element == 'number';
```

Comment: I tried typing: 'if (typeof elements == 'number' || elements === 0)' but that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: @TrailorLord , have edit my answer  to provide fix. Problem was with returning `0` which gets casted to `false`. Your provided condition won't help. The first expression `typeof elements == 'number' ` will return true for `0` and then next expression won't be checked. [Read short circuit evaluation](https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-conditionals-bbc13ac3e9eb?gi=2b0aa0ea984f). thus even with that condition `0` will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You problem can be downgraded to

```
function checkIfNumber (elements) {
  if ((typeof elements == 'number')){
    return elements
  }
}
console.log([3].every(checkIfNumber)); //true
console.log([0].every(checkIfNumber)); //false
console.log(['str'].every(checkIfNumber)); //false
```

Array.every expect true / false on callback return,
but return 0 == return false.
So you can fix it in this way

```
if ((typeof elements == 'number')){
    return true
}
```